# Taxonomy name is WordPress menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this plugin to automatically generate my menus in WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jc-submenu/

I am trying to output the taxonomy term it belongs to; in this case the product manufacturer. This code I am using outputs the **custom post type** it belongs to in front of the product name.

I tried using *get_the_terms()* function, and I'm not even sure if that's right, but how would I implement it into the below code?

```
add_filter('jcs/item_title', 'jc_edit_item_title', 10, 3);

function jc_edit_item_title($item_type, $item_id, $title) {

    $manufacturers = get_the_terms( $id, 'product-manufacturer' );

    if ($item_type == 'term') {
        $title .= ' (term)';
    } elseif ($item_type == 'page') {
        $title .= ' (page)';
    } else {
        $title .= " $item_type";
    }

    return $title;
}
```

[image: Custom WordPress Menu]